# Duplicate rules on large data volume

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

As per Salesforce docs, "In an org with many records, duplicate jobs can fail.". But is there any guidelines on counts?
src: [Things to Know About Duplicate Jobs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_jobs_considerations.htm&type=5)

Will it be good to use below 10 million records? Or there will be performance issues.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: Barring some really odd skewing in your actual dups; 10M records should be fine.

Comment: It is also worth reviewing [Duplicate Job failing with a non-specific error message](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003ecYQAQ)

Comment: @cropredy will skewing impact execution of duplication rules. I guess, skewing will only play a role when we will actually merge the duplicate records.

Comment: Swetha provided a better reference for what I meant by "skewing"

Comment: Okay, I was thinking about duplicate merge.